# Show that the three vectors (a, 1, 1), (0, b, 1) and (0, 0, c) are linearly independent only if abc is not equal to 0.

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix I though of using was \begin{bmatrix}a&0&0\\1&b&0\\1&1&c\end{bmatrix} and then solve it using Gauss elimination. However, another thought was of course that if abc = 0 then either a, b or c is 0. So, if abc is not zero then the real number λ1 used in the linear combination would be 0. But that is as far as I have gotten!

Comment: What do you need Gaus elimination for? The determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of its main diagonal elements, and there you have your proof at once...

Comment: The matrix is already triangular. Gaussian elimination would amount to swaping the first and third rows. Once you've done that it is easy to see that the matrix is full rank as long as $a\ne0, b\ne0, c\ne0$. Finally, since the matrix has full rank, the columns are linearly independent. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Three vectors are linearly independent **only if they are not coplanar**. We only need to check for their non-coplanarity in this case. For three non-coplanar vectors, their scalar product $[a \space b \space  c]$ must be non-zero (Scalar product represents the volume of the enclosed parallelopiped, which is zero if all three vectors are coplanar). The scalar product is given by 
$$[a \space b \space  c] = \begin{array}{|c c c|} a & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & b & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & c\end{array} = abc$$

Thus, **If $abc$ is not $0$, then the vectors are linearly independent**

Answer (score 0):

Three vectors $\vec u,\vec v,\vec w$ are independent if given three scalars $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ then $$\alpha\vec u+\beta\vec v+\gamma\vec w=\vec 0\iff \alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$$

If you write this with matrix this gives:

$\hphantom{..}\begin{matrix}\vec u&\vec v&\vec w&\,\,\,X\end{matrix}\\\begin{bmatrix}a&0&0\\1&b&0\\1&1&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{or simply}\quad MX=0$

This system has unique solution $X=0$ only when $M$ inversible $\iff \det(M)=abc\neq0$